# Faster processing in php: Multiple $_GETs or copy to new variable?

Tags: php, get

I am doing the finishing microoptimizations on my site and noticed that in many of my php files that are called via AJAX, I have a $_GET variable that is used many times in the php file:

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$var = $_GET['x'];

$var1 = $var . "...";
$var2 = $var . $var;

$sql = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT user FROM login WHERE login_id = '$var'");

//etc.
```

At this point, my thinking is that if the code was rewritten as:

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$var1 = $_GET['x'] . "...";
$var2 = $_GET['x'] . $_GET['x'];

$sql = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT user FROM login WHERE login_id =  
'".$_GET['x']."'");

//etc.
```

this, while equivalent in output to the first block of code, would actually be slower because the code must $_GET 'x' 4 SEPARATE times versus once in the first block of code. The first is faster because this copy of $_GET['x'] is accessed and processed more quickly. Similarly, I imagine this would also apply to php functions () and $_POST such as the following:

```
$unixtime = time();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
$TimeVar = $unixtime; //Good....a copy of time() is used each time, so time is 
calculated only once   
}
```

vs:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
$TimeVar = time(); //Bad....time() is recalculated for each iteration of the while loop
}
```

So, do $_GETs and $_POSTs get processed separately for each instance? Functions such as time()?
Sorry for the beginner's level questions...hope it is OK :)

Comment: What is the actual question? :)

Comment: Code 1 vs code 2 will perform exactly the same. You don't have to "get" the $_GET array every time you use it. php processes the query string before the scripts runs and it exists just as any other variable after that.

Comment: Sorry about that! Added questions at end

Comment: Perhaps you should worry about security and the sql injection before "micro-optimizations" like this. In your code 3 and code 4, yes, calling time once before the loop will perform better. However you are looking at possibly saving a few thousandths of a millisecond for a script that probably takes 5-6 milliseconds to completely run. Don't waste your time. 3hz of cpu would be enough to compensate for the offset.

Comment: I know about mysqli_real_escape_string and strip_tags and trim and urlencode etc....but thanks. Just wondered about the processing

Comment: OK...downvote for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SERVER`, `$_SESSION`, etc. are all global variables that are initialized once at the beginning of script processing. It doesn't matter if you access it once, or a million times, the time it takes to create the variable will be the same.

That said, assigning a given value to a variable *might* give you a bit of a performance *difference*. The array lookup of `$_GET['x']`, since it has to parse the string, go to the data structure, and pull it from there, might take a bit of time. However, assigning it to a variable might make the engine use more memory (I don't know if PHP does copy-on-write or not), and possibly do more swapping from cache to memory and back as it has to access a different variable.

That said, any differences would be on the order of tenths or hundredths of a millisecond to page load. Significantly less than you could possibly measure, and much less than the typical variation of a page load.

Comment: Great answer....where I am coming from is that if I have a couple of thousand instances of "inefficient" code, this would add up to a not-insignificant amount of time....not a crazy notion. The best example I can imagine right now is if the "inefficiency" is in a while or foreach loop....imagine if the inefficient code block (let's use your number....one-tenth of a millisecond) is in a 1000-iteration foreach loop. Shouldn't the inefficient-code-block foreach loop execute (all else being equal) 1000 x 0.0001 seconds = 0.1 seconds slower? This in my mind is not an insignificant amt of time.

Comment: @ChemBlob999: I was intending to say that, over the course of thousands of such changes, you might make a hundredth of a second difference, not that you'd be making that much each.

However, my main point is that this sort of micro-optimization is not worth the time. You're *much* better off focusing on larger optimizations, and/or upgrading your hardware. That's where you'd start to see real gains.